# resolving org.apache.jasper.JasperException

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, struts2

I have a small web application written using Java  programming language . whenever I am trying to access a jsp page I am getting the following error..................

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /jsp/newInvoice_acct_not_in_db.jsp(101,3) The s:hidden tag declares that it accepts dynamic attributes but does not implement the required interface
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:148)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:777)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1512)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2343)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2393)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2399)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:489)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2343)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validate(Validator.java:1739)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:166)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:315)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:295)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:282)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:586)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Someone please help me find the solution for it..........

Comment: Please create a minimally failing JSP page and post the source, otherwise we're just guessing. Also state which exact version of Struts 2 you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Your jSP has an compilation issue...Check whether your JSP fine

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong with a hidden tag in your JSP.  Check the Struts 2 documentation on hidden tags (http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/hidden.html) to make sure everything's compliant.  Try removing it temporarily, and if that fixes the problem start changing bits and pieces of it until you know what the problem is.  Also, are you using Eclipse?  If not you should, because it will make it a lot easier to figure out where things have gone wrong with your tags.